# Combining ngClick with ngSwitch

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know this is a scoping issue, but I can't seem to figure it out. I want to simply change one div into another one by pressing a button. In other words, `ng-click` will perform the necessary changes for `ng-switch` to activate.

However, my buttons are both nested within their respective `ng-switch-when` `div` so I'm assuming that is the problem.

Here is a fiddle of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/gGKGX/8/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular, ng-switch creates a new scope, which means that variables set in a `ng-switch` constructs aren't accessible outside of it.

In your current scenario as you have defined `thingToShow` in controller use `$parent.thingToShow` like

```
<button ng-click="$parent.thingToShow='two'">Switch!</button>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/gGKGX/12/)

Comment: This doesn't switch it back, probably because the $parent scope changes after the first switch? I get what you're saying though

Comment: There's a typo in both the OP and this fiddle. Second ng-click contains thingtoShow and not thingToShow.

Comment: @GruffBunny, Thanks yep there was a typo. Updated link

Comment: That makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks, guys. This is the closest answer to the question (even though Ken's answer is probably a more maintainable solution) so I accepted this one. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could have ngClick call a function which updates the `thingToShow` on the scope.

http://jsfiddle.net/gGKGX/9/

JS:

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("MainController", function($scope) {

    $scope.thingToShow = "one";

    $scope.showThing = function (thing) {
        $scope.thingToShow = thing;        
    };
});
```

View:

```
<div  ng-controller="MainController" ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-switch="thingToShow">
        <div ng-switch-when="one">
            Showing Thing One
            <button ng-click="showThing('two')">Switch!</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="two">
            Showing Thing Two
            <button ng-click="showThing('one')">Switch!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers you can use an object value (since things like strings aren't passed through the isolate scope set up by the switch) http://jsfiddle.net/gGKGX/14/

```
// dom
<div ng-switch="thingToShow.val">
    <div ng-switch-when="one">
        Showing Thing One
        <button ng-click="thingToShow.val = 'two';">Switch!</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="two">
        Showing Thing Two
        <button ng-click="thingToShow.val = 'one';">Switch!</button>
    </div>
</div>
// Ctrl
$scope.thingToShow = {val: "one"};
```